# Expected value inequality using Jensen

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, proof-verification

Let $X$ be a random variable and let $p\in(0,\infty)$ such that $\mathbf{E}(|X|^p)<\infty$. 
Prove that for all $q\in(0,p)$, we have $\mathbf{E}(|X|^q)\leqslant [\mathbf{E}(|X|^p)]^{\frac{q}{p}}$. You can use that $|x|^r$ is convex for all $r\geqslant 1$.

**My try**. Consider the random variable $X^p$. From $p>0$ and $0<q<p$, we have $0<\frac{q}{p}<1$. This means that $f(x)= |x|^{q/p}$ is concave, but then $g(x)= -|x|^{q/p}$ is convex. From Jensen's Inequality we get $\mathbf{E}[-f(X^p)]=-\mathbf{E}[f(X^p)]\geqslant -f[\mathbf{E}(X^p)] \iff \mathbf{E}[f(X^p)]\leqslant f[\mathbf{E}(X^p)]$. This gives
$$\mathbf{E}[|X^p|^{\frac{q}{p}}]\leqslant [\mathbf{E}(|X^p|)]^{\frac{q}{p}} \iff \mathbf{E}(|X|^q)\leqslant [\mathbf{E}(|X|^p)]^{\frac{q}{p}}$$
as asked.

**My thoughts**

I would like to know how I can use the fact that $\mathbf{E}(|X|^p)<\infty$. Also, when I look at the graph of $g$, it is not convex for all values of $x$, only on the right and left branch separately. Do I need to split cases in my proof for that? I would also like to know if there is a cleaner or better proof.

Comment: This is related to the Lyapunov inequality discussed here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289607/the-map-gt-ext-frac-1t-is-monotonic/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may look at $g(x)=-x^{q/p}$ on $x\geq 0$ side, and consider the random variable $|X|^{p}$. The assumption that $E(|X|^{p})<\infty$ is for the purpose when you put the real number $E(|X|^{p})$ into $g(\cdot)$.

Another way:

For the convex function $\varphi(x)=x^{p/q}$ on $x\geq 0$, then $[E(|X|^{q})]^{p/q}\leq E[\varphi(|X|^{q})]=E(|X|^{p})$, then $E(|X|^{q})\leq [E(|X|^{p})]^{q/p}$.

Comment: What confuses me is, why was given that $|x|^r$ is convex for all $r\geqslant 1$, if I need to look at $-x^{q/p}$?

Comment: Details added, please take a look.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not answer my question. Why the absolute values?

Comment: I think that is a little strange, if we use $|x|^{r}$ ($r=p/q>1$), we still need to put $|X|^{q}$, not only $X^{q}$, because negative number does not have meaning in real for taking exponent.

Comment: Anyway, $|x|^{r}$ and my writing that $x^{r}$ for $x\geq 0$ do not make any difference, but we must put the random variable $|X|^{q}$ (or $|X|^{p}$ for $g$).

Comment: It is clear, thanks, I will rewrite my proof.